# cannot resolve putextra method

Tags: android, android-intent

i'm trying to send an image from an arraylist one activity to another through intent in recyclerView. But in putextra method it shows error like cannot resolve method 'putextra(java.lang.string,android.widget.imageview)'

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImageView img = images.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Result.class);
            intent.putExtra("Image",img);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: we can't  pass any view using intent , if you want to send image then you can send image uri, file , or url using intent and get it in  second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day finally i did it, you simply create an array of images(NOTE: don't create arrayList) in case u want to choose between multiple images and simply pass these images through an integer. below is the code...

public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

```
    holder.image.setImageResource(images[position]);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int img = images[position];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Result.class);
            intent.putExtra("Images", img);
            intent.putExtra("personName", Name);
            intent.putExtra("Gender", Gender);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

//In targeted activity

public void getdata(){

```
    if (getIntent().getExtras() !=null) {

        gender = getIntent().getStringExtra("Gender");
        Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("personName");
        int image = getIntent().getIntExtra("Images",0);
        mytext(gender,Name,image);
    }
}
public void mytext(String gender,String Name,int img){
    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    textView2 =findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.Imagename);
    textView1.setText(Name);
    textView2.setText(gender);
    imageView.setImageResource(img);
}
```

//then in onCreate method call "getdata();"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an `ImageView`as an extra, the object you are passing must be a Parcelable or a Serialiazable.

Your ImageView is also relevant for this activity only. If you are trying to send an Image to another activity, it is better to send the path to the image.

Comment: can u plz explain parcelable object

Comment: Zohaib bro there is a ArrayList of images and i want to send only one image according to the position, plz help me with that

Comment: If you have the path to the image or a resource id, send that instead. Read about parcelable here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49252418/3266367

Comment: @AwaisAslam where is this ArrayList loaded from? Where do these images come from?

Comment: Also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407644/3266367) for sending drawables in intent (not recommended however)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send `image` directly because `intent` does not support it

**Try this Solution**

You can send `image` using `ByteArray` though eg

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImageView img = images.get(position);
            img.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Result.class);
            intent.putExtra("Image", byteArray);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

in `onCreate()` of **Result Activity class**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("Image");
//convert it to bitmap again
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//set image to bitmap
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

SOURCE
[Passing image from one activity another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity)

Comment: i tried it, But it Crashes app at "imageView img=images.get(position)"

Comment: can you plz tell me some other way, basically i'm trying to send choosen image from recycler view to other activity

Comment: post your recycler adapter and activity class also the POJO Class