# What is parcelable and why it is used for BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE?

Tags: android

I am learning about bluetooth functionality in android. I came across `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE` and `intent.getParcelable()`. My question is what is parcelable and why is it used with `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE` and `intent.getParcelable()`

I referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249234/what-is-parcelable-in-android) but it doesn't answer

> why is it used with `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Parcelable in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249234/what-is-parcelable-in-android)

Comment: But why is it used with `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE`?

Answer (score 0):

`EXTRA_DEVICE` contains the BluetoothDevice that the intent applies to.

`device` has information about device name, address, type,...

Comment: I want to know why do we need to use `intent.getParcelableExtra()` for getting `EXTRA_DEVICE`.