# app crashes because of nav component argument when putting the app in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, arguments

I get the following error when I put my app in the background, or when I press the recent apps button while in the app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.mappractice.data.LocationItem)
```

This is the class which generates the error(this is used as an argument for a fragment):

```
data class LocationItem(
    val name: String,
    val locations: List<Place>
): Serializable
```

This is where the argument is used:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val location = args.location

        binding.mapView.getMapAsync(object : OnMapReadyCallback {
            override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
                val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.builder()

                for (place in location.locations) {
                    val locationPoz = LatLng(place.lat, place.long)
                    boundsBuilder.include(locationPoz)

                    val marker = MarkerOptions()
                        .position(locationPoz)
                        .title(place.name)

                    googleMap.addMarker(marker)
                }

                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                    boundsBuilder.build(),
                    800,
                    800,
                    0))
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: What if you used a Parcelable class instead `@Parcelize
data class LocationItem(
    val name: String,
    val locations: List<Place>
): Parcelable` ?

Comment: What does parcelable means

Comment: It's the android right implementation of Serializable.. but it's greater performance.. check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249234/what-is-parcelable-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Even using @Parcelize and Parcelable, the app crashes when going background or starting another Activity. Log showed "java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB".
The problem was that I had a duplicate attribute, for example:

```
@ Parcelize
data class League(
     val matches: List<Match>?,
...
) : Parcelable
```

and

```
@ Parcelize
data class Match(
     val league: League?,
...
) : Parcelable
```

It was in loop. When I changed the attribute by creating another model `"val league: LeagueInfo?"` the problem was solved.